# What is the amount of test data needed to evaluate a CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, training, testing, data-augmentation

I have an image dataset of about 400 images. 70% of these data points were used for training, 15% for validation, and 15% for testing. I am using the 70% to train a CNN-based binary classifier. I augmented the *training* data to around 8000 images. That makes my test set really small in comparison. Is that ok, and what is considered a decent size of images for a test set?

Comment: Also, I am an hs student who is really new to machine learning and would appreciate any advice :)

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the task. I know I have previously achieved high accuracy on MNIST with a similarly low amount of training data.